# Is a SQL Server index B-tree a flat structure or a depth structure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, data-structures, indexing

I was asked this question on the interview a few minutes ago and I didnt know the answer. I answered it logically thinking that a B-Tree is always a depth structure because it has multiple levels. Was I right on my answer? 
What would be the best way to answer this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you were right in both your answer and your reasoning. A tree is never a flat structure. An example of a flat structure would be a single dimension array.

Answer (score 2):

B-tree hence the name will be a tree or depth structure.

Answer (score 1):

You were right.  Whether the person asking the question also had the right answer is unknown.

Comment: Point! I am sure he just wanted to ask a question since it was an interview.